# Raspian Reset because of Widevine for libreelec

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, boot-issues

i just had to reset my Raspian Image on my SD Card because it wasnt booting up. The only thing it showed me for hours was a blackscreen.

Im using Berryboot to start Raspian 2018, LibreELEC 9.0 and RetroPIE 4.4

In a Widevine Update for Netflix on Libreelec i got a 2.0GB Update message and installed it. after that netflix worked again but after a quick reboot i only got a blackscreen from raspian. After i resetted the Rasbian Image fully i got a normal screen again.
To stop this from happening again, i want to split the allocated memory for libreelec. so it cant use the memory of raspian or retropie (overwrite it). I want to do that on my windows 10 PC

Comment: the 2GB update has nothing to do with the issue. Since the 2GB file is only needed temporarily to extract the widevine.so after which, the chromium image is deleted - something else is wrong with your system

Comment: Your question is confusing. I don't understand it. What does it mean: reset the Raspbian Image? Does it  mean to flash the SD Card again from the image? And do you want to split the allocated memory for libreelec on your windows 10 PC? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: Reset is a function in berryboot. So you can reset the operating system completely. I want to split the memory on the sd card for libreelec.